# Can the ews-javascript-api be used in a standard web application and accessed via Chrome?

Tags: ews-javascript-api

I am trying to use the ews-javascript-api in a web application, but as it seems to be based on Nodejs I am unable to get the scripts to run properly. I added requirejs, but now I get the error `"Uncaught Error: Module name "../ExchangeWebService" has not been loaded yet for context: _. Use require([])"`

Is is possible to access the ExchangeWebService.js file from a web browser and if so, how do I get the dependencies set up correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not easy though. Microsoft does not implement CORS on Exchange Server and Chrome must use CORS pre-flight for you to access exchange server. if you are working on enterprise application using ews-javascript-api, you can use some proxy in middle which would override CORS restriction and you can then use it in Chrome. for testing purpose if you disable CORS in Chrome, you can use it. nginx or even IIS can be used to override this limitation, not sure your use case.

you have to use specifically built module https://github.com/gautamsi/ews-js-api-browser to use with browser based access.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply and thanks so much for building this awesome library.  I actually was using the ews-js-api-browser version, but still encountered the error.  I was able to get it to work by using browserify, after which I got the error above.  I'll try a proxy since I don't have the ability to disable CORS on the Exchange service side.  Thanks again.

Comment: ping me on gitter, I can try give more detail for complex way of using in chrome. gitter userid: gautamsi

Comment: I figured it out.  I misunderstood the shift to browser usage and grabbed the wrong ExchangeService.js file.  Once I get the correct one and refactored my code, it worked perfectly.  Also, while my implementation requires the browser version of the code, it's being accessed via an application-embedded browser so CORS is actually not an issue.  Thank you so much for this library, it's fantastic!  One final thing: how should I reference your license for my plugin that calls your library?

Comment: It's MIT license, I do not require or enforce attribution, this qn will help you determine this clearly - https://opensource.stackexchange.com/questions/5828/where-would-i-give-credit-to-an-mit-licensed-project-in-an-ios-app

Comment: if anyone has done this, why not share the ready-to-use js file, please ? :) I tried to build https://github.com/gautamsi/ews-js-api-browser but npm gives me errors. Consequently solving them: package name = target, absent browserfy, error in internal chils process :) The instructions from readme do not work straight away :)

Comment: open an issue there, the ews-js-browser-api is stale by few versions but still available on npm.